# spray-client: log the actual HTTP sent / recieved over the wire

Tags: scala, spray, spray-client

In Apache HTTP Client there's the concept of a "wire log" that can be turned on, printing out the actual HTTP text generated by the client code and sent to the server.

How can I do the same using spray-client? I'm of course able to add a RequestTransformer and ResponseTransformer and print them using .toString, but that doesn't show me what's actually being serialized to HTTP at the TCP level.

Comment: I don't know the right answer, but i think that you should take a look at spray-can, rather then spray-client.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "wire log".

Comment: the raw HTTP that gets sent over the TCP layer